# Facebook's Like Box not working with a .GOV domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

From this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box - After using several .gov domains - cops.usdoj.gov, opm.gov & bls.gov - I get this error message: The page you requested was not found.

It appears the like box is not working with a .gov domain

Here's my set of code:

iframe
iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fcops.usdoj.gov%2F&width=200&colorscheme=light&connections=5&stream=false&header=true&height=287" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:287px;" allowTransparency="true"

XFBML
script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">/script fb:like-box href="http://cops.usdoj.gov/" width="200" connections="5" stream="false" header="true" /fb:like-box

Answer (score 0):

Mark, I think where you may be going astray is plugging those .gov URLs into the Facebook Page URL box. The Facebook Page URL box is for URLs to Facebook pages. So:

1. Set up Facebook pages for each of these government agencies, if that is what you are trying to do.
2. Each of those pages should be associated with a Facebook URL, hypothetical example:

http://www.facebook.com/#!/MartiansHaveLanded

1. Paste the Facebook page URL - http://www.facebook.com/#!/MartiansHaveLanded -
   into the Facebook Page URL box

That should result in the correct code being generated.